# Cross-platform use of web api. How it is better to organize operation on all devices?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cross-platform, nuget

The help of professionals in web API from Microsoft is necessary!

There is written many me web API. It is successfully used on mobile devices.

I work with API on devices through the class restsharp. With it everything is good. But there was the following task.

I want to make a site through which it will be possible to be authorized using login and the password, data is used in web API.

How it is better to make? Also to make through restsharp? It is necessary council! Excuse for my English!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, restsharp is clientside Framework, it has nothing to do with the Server side implementation.

Since the REST API is stateless by nature (no client context being stored on the server between requests). because of that you have to use Auth Tokens.

Basic Scenario:

1. Client sends the loging/Password data to the Auth Service.
2. Auth Service verifies that the date is valid and creates Simple Web Token as a result.
3. Client takes the token and incorporate it into all REST API requests via the Authentication HTTP header.
4. You web api on the Server side extracts the Token from the Header and validates the Token.
5. Token is valid => User is allowed to call the REST API.

Token Validation:
In order to validate the token on the Server side you have to share the "secret" key between Auth Server and your API Service. Because Tokens are signed with this key.

Comment: I and so use restsharp on the party of the client. The matter is that the standard ms web api project uses already authorization mechanisms through token.

Comment: At me in the ios appendix the token remains statically. To use it later. Tell for a version web connection to base and an avtoriazation it is necessary on a straight line or also through api? Чтобы мне было проще, вы не русский? :)